# How to connect my Ionic app with my java server(Spring MVC)?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, ionic-framework

first of all: i am completey new to ionic!

I have experience in Java programing. And i have to program a application for my studies.

**How do i connect ionic with java ?**

I found many examples using java programming like Restful web services and other example used javascript.

Thanks

Comment: Have u got the solution..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet for integrating an Ionic app/client with a java server is going to be loading JSON data over HTTP.

See the documentation on the Angular HTTP module here. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Another option would be to return HTML, but you'll lose a lot of benefits of Angular presenting it this way.

Thanks, Dan